# pandas making a new column with multiple strings from another column

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a column with values that look like `A_B_C_D`. I want to create a new column that grabs the first and the last values to create `A_D`. I used split + and but that didn't work. It created the new cols but gave me all nans. There are nans present in the first column.

```
dfNC['collapsedntdom'] = np.where(dfNC[ntdom].isnull(), dfNC[ntdom],
                                  (dfNC[ntdom].str.split('_')[0]) and "_" and (dfNC[ntdom].str.split('_')[3]))
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a efficient method (`apply` is slow):

```
df['new_col'] = (  df['col'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True)[0]
                 + '_'
                 + df['col'].str.rsplit('_', 1, expand=True)[1]
                )
```

example:

```
            col  new_col
0           NaN      NaN
1       1_2_3_4      1_4
2       A_B_C_D      A_D
3  abc_def__ghi  abc_ghi
```

#### generic method

Now is a generic method to combine arbitrary positions (here 0/2/-1):

```
from functools import reduce
df2 = df['col'].str.split('_', expand=True).iloc[:, [0, 2, -1]]
df['new_col'] = reduce(lambda a,b: (None, a[1]+'_'+b[1]), df2.iteritems())[1]
```

output:

```
            col   new_col
0           NaN       NaN
1       1_2_3_4     1_3_4
2       A_B_C_D     A_C_D
3  abc_def__ghi  abc__ghi
```

Comment: thank you. your first solution is what I'm looking for but the function is great too. Can you explain why you have a 1 inside the split?

Comment: This is to limit the split to 1 times (*e.g.*, `'a_b_c_d` -> `a`+`b_c_d`). Not strictly required but improves a bit performance ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution, and it will work in your case:

```py
dfNC['collapsedntdom'] = dfNC['ntdom'].apply(lambda x: x if str(x)=='nan' else f"{x.split('_')[0]}_{x.split('_')[3]}")
```

The output being:

```
    ntdom   collapsedntdom
0   A_B_C_D A_D
1   E_F_G_H E_H
2   NaN NaN
3   J_K_L_M J_M
```